# Dicionário, separar valores e chaves em duas listas

Tags: python

Eu tenho o seguinte dicionário:

```
abc = {'y': 'Y', 'b': 'B', 'e': 'E', 'x': 'X', 'v': 'V', 't': 'T', 'f': 'F', 'w': 'W', 'g': 'G', 'o': 'O', 'j': 'J', 'm': 'M', 'z': 'Z', 'h': 'H', 'd': 'D', 'r': 'R', 'l': 'L', 'p': 'P', 'a': 'A', 's': 'S', 'k': 'K', 'n': 'N', 'q': 'Q', 'i': 'I', 'u': 'U', 'c': 'C'}
```

O que eu queria é separar os valores e as chaves em duas listas diferentes. E ordenar cada uma, o resultado que eu quero:

```
lista_peq = ['a', 'b', 'c' ...]
lista_grd = ['A', 'B', 'C' ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta solução que lhe vou dar funciona tanto em python 2.7.x como em python 3.x.x.

Para separar

```
abc = {'y': 'Y', 'b': 'B', 'e': 'E', 'x': 'X', 'v': 'V', 't': 'T', 'f': 'F', 'w': 'W', 'g': 'G', 'o': 'O', 'j': 'J', 'm': 'M', 'z': 'Z', 'h': 'H', 'd': 'D', 'r': 'R', 'l': 'L', 'p': 'P', 'a': 'A', 's': 'S', 'k': 'K', 'n': 'N', 'q': 'Q', 'i': 'I', 'u': 'U', 'c': 'C'}
```

em duas listas, uma com as letras minúsculas e outra com as maiúsculas e ordena-las faça assim:

```
lista_peq = sorted(abc.keys()) #['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
lista_grd = sorted(abc.values()) #['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

`abc.values()` vai extrair os valores e `abc.keys()` vai extrair as chaves. O método `sorted(...)` no caso de ser python 2.7.x vai ordenar alfabéticamente, e no caso de ser python 3.x para além de ordenar também vai converter em lista implicitamente. Para converter só em lista (sem ser ordenada) em python 3.x seria `list(abc.keys())` e `list(abc.values())`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta